# Run GWT project on TomCat 7

Tags: tomcat, gwt, intellij-idea

I've created my first GWT project with help of Intellij Idea. But when I deploy it on TomCat I see an error **GWT module 'project' may need to be (re)compiled**.  I red here a lot of questions from the people with the same problems. But resolutions from these questions didn't help me.

I think problem is in the file **project\war\project\project.nocache.js**. Because without this file my project sends SQL queries. I saw them in the Tomcat log file. But I see a blank page without this file.
Maybe I need to regenerate this file somehow, but I don't know how.

Please, suggest me, how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you GWTCompile the project? What was the output?

Comment: What do you mean as GWTCompile? I can't find such in my Intellij Idea.

Comment: Please, help. It's really grieve to have a ready project and can't deploy it.

Comment: You have to compile your project using a GWT Compiler. https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_compile

Comment: I use Intellij Idea instead of Eclipse. And this GWT Compiler is for Eclipse. I can't use it in Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a new project in Intellij Idea and I've copied sources and libraries from the old project. Now it deploys without errors.